# Mongodb erase documents which have expired (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema the following schema

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    min: Date.now(),
  },
});
```

I want the documents which have expired based on the field `date` of this schema to be deleted at the end of the day. For example, let's say I insert a document with the `date` field: 2021-07-05 10:00 am, I want this document to be deleted at the end of that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expire data from collection by setting **[Time to live](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)**.

Comment: I don't have a specific number of seconds after which the documents will expire. I want for any date I insert into the database the document to expire at the end of the day of that date.

Comment: Then scroll down the page to [Expire Documents at a Specific Clock Time](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time)

Comment: You're right, didn't understand it completely the first time had to reread it. Thanks you